# Disconnect client from server

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing client server program I want to close the connection between them after message sent, how would I go about doing that? Is there any way to disconnect a client from thread in server?
I wrote this for client :

```
client.m_client.disconnect();
```

and this for server:

```
connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));

void mythread::disconnected()
{
    qDebug() << " Disconnected";

    socket->deleteLater();

    exit(0);
}
```